# Jquery not firing inside handlebars template

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have Javascript directory search that uses jquery and jquery UI code that works on it's own page but as soon as I use the handlebars templates, the on submit function isn't registering or firing anything:

```
$(".navbar-form").submit(function () {
        var a = $("#searchFullName").val();
        var currentTab = '';
        $('li.active').each(function(index) {
           currentTab = $(this).find('a').html();       
        });
        getFirstAndLastName(a);
        if(currentTab == 'Student')
            callStudentWebService();
        if(currentTab == 'Faculty/Staff')
            callStaffWebService();
        $('#searchFullName').blur();
        return false;
});
```

HTML and JS pasted here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Cr9s/

Is it possible to reload the Javascript file(s) when a template changes in handlebars? I'm really stuck here.

Comment: use event delegation for the submit event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much charlietfl!

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "form", "submit", function() { 
...
```

This worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case where I use select with event delegation

```
$("body").delegate('select[name="carType"]', 'change',function () {
        var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
        var val = this.value;
});
```